# Hermite normal form of infinite matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, linear-diophantine-equations, infinite-matrices, hermite-normal-form

I have an infinite matrix $A$ that is in row echelon form, except zeros are to the right of each pivot, as shown below. The $*$ symbol denotes any integer, though most of them are zero.

$A= \left( \begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1&0&0&0&0&0&\dots \\
 *&*&1&0&0&0&\dots \\
 *&*&*&1&0&0&\dots \\
 *&*&*&*&*&1&\dots \\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots \\
 \end{array} \right)$

I want to calculate the column Hermite normal form of $A$. Without doing any calculations, it seems like an infinite number of column operations would yield

$H= \left( \begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1&0&0&0&0&0&\dots \\
 0&0&1&0&0&0&\dots \\
 0&0&0&1&0&0&\dots \\
 0&0&0&0&0&1&\dots \\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots \\
 \end{array} \right)$

Is that correct? Also, once I have the column Hermite normal form $H$, how can I use it to solve 
$A \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ with integer solutions for $\mathbf{x}$?